# java calculator- clearing accumulator

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button, calculator

So far in my calculator, I can input the problem and get the correct solution. My issue is when I click the clear button (to clear the accumulator and start a new problem) it sets the text box blank but keeps the stored values. I tried creating a reset method in my accumulator class but so far I am stuck. Any tips??

```
import acm.program.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;    // for graphics 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import acm.gui.*;
public class Calculator extends DialogProgram implements ActionListener{ 


JButton b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,bm,bd,ba,bs,bdec,bc,bequ;
DoubleField screen = new DoubleField();

JPanel P,P1,P2;
Accumulator acc = new Accumulator();
double result;

public void init() {


//create a panel 


JPanel P= new JPanel();     // main panel 

JPanel P1= new JPanel();    // panel for buttons 

JPanel P2= new JPanel();    // panel for screen

// adding panel to dialog box

add(P);        // main panel 
P.add(P2);     // adding screen
P.add(P1);     // adding panel of buttons 

// set panel color 
P.setBackground(Color.yellow);                 


// grid layout for buttons 

P1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,4,4,4));           // layout for button panel 
P.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));                // layout for main panel 

// create screen 
//screen = new DoubleField();                      // creating screen 
screen.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,40));  // setting screen size 
screen.setEditable(false);                       // screen can not be edited 

// integer buttons 
b0 = new JButton("0");
b1 = new JButton("1");
b2 = new JButton("2");
b3 = new JButton("3");
b4 = new JButton("4");
b5 = new JButton("5");
b6 = new JButton("6");
b7 = new JButton("7");
b8 = new JButton("8");
b9 = new JButton("9");

// operator buttons 
bm = new JButton("*");
bd= new  JButton("/");
ba = new JButton("+"); 
bs = new JButton("-");

// decimal button 
bdec = new JButton(".");

// clear button
bc = new JButton("Clr");

// equal button
bequ = new JButton("=");

// adding buttons to panel 
P2.add(screen);
P1.add(b7);
P1.add(b8);
P1.add(b9);
P1.add(bm);
P1.add(b4);
P1.add(b5);
P1.add(b6);
P1.add(bd);
P1.add(b1);
P1.add(b2);
P1.add(b3);
P1.add(ba);
P1.add(bc);
P1.add(b0);
P1.add(bdec);
P1.add(bs);
P1.add(bequ);

// adding action listeners 
 bm.addActionListener(this); 
 bd.addActionListener(this); 
 bs.addActionListener(this); 
 ba.addActionListener(this);
 b9.addActionListener(this); 
 b8.addActionListener(this); 
 b7.addActionListener(this); 
 b6.addActionListener(this); 
 b5.addActionListener(this); 
 b4.addActionListener(this); 
 b3.addActionListener(this); 
 b2.addActionListener(this); 
 b1.addActionListener(this); 
 b0.addActionListener(this); 
 bdec.addActionListener(this); 
 bc.addActionListener(this); 
 bequ.addActionListener(this);



 //addActionListeners();


} // close 

//public static void main(String[] args) {
//  new Calculator().start(args);   



//}


public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
     String clicked =e.getActionCommand();
     if (clicked.equals("1")) {
         screen.setText(screen.getText()+clicked);
     }  
     if (clicked.equals("2")) {
         screen.setText(screen.getText()+clicked);
     }
     if (clicked.equals("3")) {
         screen.setText(screen.getText()+clicked);
     }
     if (clicked.equals("4")) {
         screen.setText(screen.getText()+clicked);
     }
     if (clicked.equals("5")) {
         screen.setText(screen.getText()+clicked);
     }
     if (clicked.equals("6")) {
         screen.setText(screen.getText()+clicked);
     }
     if (clicked.equals("7")) {
         screen.setText(screen.getText()+clicked);
     }
     if (clicked.equals("8")) {
         screen.setText(screen.getText()+clicked);
     }
     if (clicked.equals("9")) {
         screen.setText(screen.getText()+clicked);
     }
     if (clicked.equals("0")) {
         screen.setText(screen.getText()+clicked);
     }
     if (clicked.equals("*")) {
        // screen.setText(screen.getText()+clicked);
         acc.calculate(screen.getValue(), "*");
         screen.setText("");
     }
     if (clicked.equals("/")) {
        // screen.setText(screen.getText()+clicked);
         acc.calculate(screen.getValue(), "/");
         screen.setText("");
     }     
     if (clicked.equals("+")) {
        // screen.setText(screen.getText()+clicked);
         acc.calculate(screen.getValue(), "+");
         screen.setText("");
     } 
     if (clicked.equals("-")) {
         acc.calculate(screen.getValue(), "-");
         screen.setText("");
     } 
     if (clicked.equals(".")) {
         screen.setText(screen.getText()+clicked);
     }
     if (clicked.equals("Clr")) {
         acc.reset();
         screen.setText("");

     } 

     if (clicked.equals("=")) {
        // screen.setText("");
         acc.calculate(screen.getValue(), "=");
         screen.setValue(acc.getValue());

        // screen.setText(result);

     } 



}/*action Performed*/


public class Accumulator{
    double valueSoFar;
    String currentOperator;

    Accumulator(){
        valueSoFar=0.0;
        currentOperator="C";

    }
    /*constructor*/

    public void calculate(double numberOnDisplay, String nextOperator) {
        if (currentOperator.contentEquals("+")) {
            valueSoFar= valueSoFar + numberOnDisplay;

        }
        if (currentOperator.contentEquals("-")) {
            valueSoFar= valueSoFar - numberOnDisplay;
        }
        if (currentOperator.contentEquals("*")) {
            valueSoFar= valueSoFar * numberOnDisplay;
        }
        if (currentOperator.contentEquals("/")) {
            valueSoFar= valueSoFar / numberOnDisplay;
        }
        if (currentOperator.equals("C")) {
            valueSoFar = numberOnDisplay;
        //  currentOperator = nextOperator;

        }
        //  getValue();

        //}




        currentOperator = nextOperator;

    }/*calculate*/

    public double getValue() {
        return valueSoFar;
        }    /*getValue*/

    public double reset() {

        return valueSoFar;
    }

}/*Accumulator*/


} /*Class*/
```

Comment: `public double reset() {return valueSoFar;}` uh? didn't you mean `valueSoFar = 0`?

Comment: There are at least 2 possible approaches: 1) provide a `reset()` that sets `valueSoFar` and `currentOperator` to the initial values like the `Accumulator()` constructor is doing 2) simply replace the "old" `Accumulator` instance with a new one (so instead of `acc.reset();` youd'd have  `acc = new Accumulator();`) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the "Clr" button, it calls the `acc.reset();`, but that returns the `valueSoFar`. You have to set `valueSoFar` to 0.0 in the Accumulator `reset()`;

```
public double reset() {
   valueSoFar = 0.0;
   return valueSoFar;
}
```